# How to input a String in java except using nextLine() and I need to print the whole statement/sentences with spaces

Tags: java

So, below in my code, I want to input a string but without using the function `nextLine()` and I need to print the whole statement with statement. And I have already tried the alternative keyword `next()` it only prints the first word and because of a space it stops. But I need to print the whole statement.

SO, in that case what should be the solution?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int i = scan.nextInt();
        double d = scan.nextDouble();
        String s = scan.next();

        // Write your code here.

        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to put an extra *scan.nextLine* before your string input scanner to consume the extra **\n** like

```
int i = scan.nextInt();
double d = scan.nextDouble();
scan.nextLine();
String s = scan.next();
```

Comment: if we use String s = scan.next(); it will only initialize the first word. To initialize the whole statement we have to use String s = scan.nextLine();

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Solution {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double d=scan.nextDouble();
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        String s=scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
 }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the scan.nextInt() method - it only reads the int value. So when you continue reading with scan.nextLine() you receive the "\n" Enter key. So to skip this you have to add the scan.nextLine().

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         int i = scan.nextInt();
         double d = scan.nextDouble();
         scan.nextLine();
         String s = scan.nextLine();
         System.out.println("String: " + s);
         System.out.println("Double: " + d);
         System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use an array to store the input from [`Scanner#next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) or a List (preferable) then simply display the contents of the list.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();

int i = scan.nextInt();
double d = scan.nextDouble();
String s = scan.next();

while(!s.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")){
       tempList.add(s);
       s = scan.next();
}

System.out.println("String: " + tempList.toString().replace("[","")
        .replace("]","").replace(",",""));
System.out.println("Double: " + d);
System.out.println("Int: " + i);
```

Answer (score 0):

> `Scanner.next()` method finds and returns the next complete token.

It is hard to do without `nextLine()` and arrays. But this what I tired to do without arrays and `nextLine()`. Somehow have to enter a value(in this case I used `-1`) to end the loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int i = scan.nextInt();
    double d = scan.nextDouble();

    boolean flag = true;
    String s="";

    System.out.println("enter -1 to exit");
    while(flag){
        s += scan.next() + " ";
        if(s.contains("-1")){
            flag = false;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("String: " + s.replace("-1", ""));
    System.out.println("Double: " + d);
    System.out.println("Int: " + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So simple just use another reference variable of Scanner variable ,
before the `.nextLine()` method reads the nextLine tokens of `.nextInt();`
hence , by creating new object it clears the temporary memory.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double d=scan.nextDouble();
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        Scanner newscan=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s=newscan.nextLine();
        // Write your code here.

        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use parse() for taking both the input of int and double

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
   
    int i=Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    double d=Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
    String s=scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("String: " + s);
    System.out.println("Double: " + d);
    System.out.println("Int: " + i);
}
```